# Using PhoneGap Media API with Ripple

Tags: cordova, media

I'm new to PhoneGap/Cordova and I'm trying to experiment with some of the API.

I have been using the documentation examples within Ripple Emulator for Chrome however when trying to use the [media example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_media_media.md.html#media.play) I get the following errors in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'hasResource'
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Am I missing something, can this be used inside the Ripple Emulator?

I've tried searching around with little information available for what I'm looking for.

Sorry if this is somewhat of a simple question but I don't seem to be able to find any info.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you see hasResource defined in the Media APi?

Comment: It's within the Chrome dev tools console area

Comment: Err, but where do you see it _documented_? Because I'm not seeing it.

Answer (score 0):

am not sure if at time of posting the version 2.0 of Cordova was released yet. But you should follow this API guide inside of the 1.0

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media